# Plotting multiple lines with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, plot

I am building an R function that would plot multiple Force Vs. Displacement lines in one graph. Here is my set of data:

```
       myrows displacememnt force displacememnt force displacememnt force displacememnt force displacememnt
[1,]      1  0.000000e+00     0  0.000000e+00     0  0.000000e+00     0  0.000000e+00     0  0.000000e+00
[2,]      2  4.292647e-08     0  8.829379e-08     0  4.194021e-08     0  4.136511e-08     0 -3.818898e-08
[3,]      3  1.284946e-09     0  1.343980e-07     0  4.665416e-08     0  3.375577e-08     0 -4.819687e-09
[4,]      4  4.380121e-08     0  1.742593e-07     0  7.184801e-09     0  3.734106e-08     0  3.210356e-08
[5,]      5  8.224440e-08     0  2.558701e-07     0  1.245641e-07     0  8.266907e-08     0  1.024775e-07
[6,]      6  1.269747e-07     0  3.842161e-07     0  1.223706e-07     0  1.666898e-07     0  1.407497e-07
```

All I want to do is plot multiple force vs. displacement within the same graph.  But I dont know how to split up the data , I tried melt function:

```
    meltedData <- melt(dataset,id.vars="myrows")
> head(meltedData)
  Var1   Var2 value
1    1 myrows     1
2    2 myrows     2
3    3 myrows     3
4    4 myrows     4
5    5 myrows     5
6    6 myrows     6
```

This is the minimal reprsentation of the dataset.

Would anyone be able to assist me to acheive my objective i.e. to plot multiple force v displacement lines within one plot?

Final plot what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You can use the `plot()` function to plot the first series, and use `lines()` or `points()`  to add subsequent series

Comment: would be a lot easier if there was a ggplot function that I can tell by splitting two columns at a time (force v disp)?

Comment: I think matplot is what you want.

Comment: btw, posting the output from `dput(dataset)` would make it easier to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your data frame has the same format you show in the example, you can break it into a long data frame with this:

```
df <- data.frame(myrows=c(1,2,3), force=c(0, 0.1, 0.2), disp=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), 
    force=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), disp=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))

new.df <- NULL
for (i in seq(2, ncol(df), 2)) {
    new.df <- rbind(new.df, data.frame(no=i/2, force=df[, i], disp=df[, i+1]))
}

library(ggplot2)
qplot(force, disp, group=no, data=new.df, col=factor(no), geom="line")
```

[image]

It's ugly, but works I guess.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works. Would you mind sharing what the plots look like in the end, if you can?

Comment: Done. I changed around the 'no' for the context of the plot.

Comment: Thanks! If you want to relabel the lines with more descriptive names, you could replace `df$no` with some more descriptive factor variable.